# Exporting FBX with texture issue

Tags: export, .fbx

I want to export an FBX mesh with texture, following the steps below, always getting the same result: a grey mesh

This is the result I would expect:

[image]

Presets I used:

[image]
[image]

aaaaaand...
[image]
great... a grey mesh

What did I do wrong ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: If you import the FBX back into Blender, do you see the texture?

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.4.1 I have a bright and color modifier in the texture and this happened. I remove it and it solved it, that means that I have to edit the texture in another software.